# Angular | is there a away to cause *ngIf run only once?

Tags: angular, typescript, permissions

I have a small problem, I need to apply roles validation at my angular application.
The application is built from pages that each page contains a number of components. 
The user privileges are granted at the components level, so sadly I can't use just route guard to grant a full page, I had to add validation for each component using a simple *ngIf:

```
     <results-component 
          *ngIf="auth.hasPermission('driver_productivity')"
          [format] = "driver_productivityFormat" 
          [IsFullWidth] = "IsFullWidth"
          (customEvent)="showPrint($event)">
     </results-component>
```

auth.service.ts:

```
hasPermission(permissionName){
if (!this.tokenPayload){
  this.getToken().subscribe(t=>{this.tokenPayload=decode(t.getValue())});
  if (this.tokenPayload.roles && this.tokenPayload.roles.length>0 ){
    this.permissions={};
    for (let i=0;i<this.tokenPayload.roles.length;i++){
      this.permissions[this.tokenPayload.roles[i]]=true
    }
  }
}
return this.permissions[permissionName]
```

}

but since I have multiple components per page, this validation accrue way too many time, so it became an abusing solution.

> [Violation] 'setInterval' handler took 150ms zone.js:1755 [Violation]
>   'click' handler took 318ms zone.js:2279 [Violation]
>   'requestAnimationFrame' handler took 84ms zone.js:1755 [Violation]
>   'click' handler took 261ms

Is there a way to make *ngIf run just once? when the component is first loaded?

Comment: We accomplished something similar--such as adding / hiding navigation elements, buttons, and other functionality--by creating our own directive.  User info, and roles, are loaded upon login and stored in a global service class. The directive input accepts the user's roles and a list of roles allowed to access the UI element.  The directive is not unlike an ngif--it creates or destroys the element based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to make *ngIf run just once? when the component is
>   first loaded?

Yes. Move the corresponding logic to the `ngOnInit(...)` method of your component. Thereby it gets executed only *once* when the component loads.

Answer (score 2):

You can either move your logic to `ngOnInit`, as already suggested, or you can built a pipe. Since pipes are memoized, the logic inside will only rerun when the input changes.

I created a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rvgjre) showcasing this.